# Can a method in a python class be annotated with a type that is defined by a subclass?

Tags: python, types, mypy

I have a superclass that has a method which is shared by its subclasses.  However, this method should return an object with a type that is defined on the subclass.  I'd like the return type for the method to be statically annotated (not a dynamic type) so code using the subclasses can benefit from `mypy` type checking on the return values. But I don't want to have to redefine the common method on the subclass just to provide its type annotation.  Is this possible with python type annotations and mypy?

Something like this:

```py
from typing import Type

class AbstractModel:
    pass

class OrderModel(AbstractModel):
    def do_order_stuff():
        pass

class AbstractRepository:
    model: Type[AbstractModel]

    def get(self) -> model:
        return self.model()

class OrderRepository(AbstractRepository):
    model = OrderModel


repo = OrderRepository()
order = repo.get()

# Type checkers (like mypy) should recognize that this is valid
order.do_order_stuff()

# Type checkers should complain about this; because `OrderModel`
# does not define `foo`
order.foo()
```

The tricky move here is that `get()` is defined on the superclass `AbstractRepository`, which doesn't yet know the type of `model`.  (And the `-> model` annotation fails, since the value of `model` hasn't been specified yet).

The value of `model` is specified by the subclass, but the subclass doesn't (re)define `get()` in order to provide the annotation.  It seems like this *should* be statically analyzable; though it's a little tricky, since it would require the static analyzer to trace the `model` reference from the superclass to the subclass.

Any way to accomplish both a shared superclass implementation and a precise subclass return type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `AbstractRepository` as a generic class.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type, ClassVar


T = TypeVar('T')

class AbstractRespotitory(Generic[T]):
    model: ClassVar[Type[T]]

    @classmethod
    def get(cls) -> T:
        return cls.model()
```

(`get` only makes use of a class attribute, so can--and arguably should--be a class method.)

Comment: For usage: subclasses need to specify the non-generic type when extending the generic, e.g. `class OrderRepository(AbstractRepository[OrderModel]):`